# Magento customer import not defined issue

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, import, csv

I want to import customers to magento via import/export profile

my csv look like this:

```
ID,Name,Company,Email,Group,Telephone,ZIP,Country,State/Province,Customer Since,Website,Controle:,Status:
1163,dhr Name,berkel management &amp; consultancy,example@hotmail.com,45%,015-2023091,2907 PE,Netherlands,,"Jun 7, 2017 9:27:00 AM",Main Website,,
```

When i run the import i receive this message:
**Skipping import row, required field "website" is not defined.**

I already changed the encoding to UTF-8.

Does anyone know where is my problem here?